# Ajax form sending file one after another

Tags: html, jquery

I have a form that I sending with ajax.
in this form there's x input file and each of them have 2 input text.

when i send the form all of the files are sent at the same times.

so what i want to do is sending one file at time with his 2 input text.

there's my code :

***HTML***

```
<div id="img_upload">
<form action="#" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="img_upload_head">
        <?php
            require MODULE.DS."galerie".DS."traitement".DS."galerie".DS."recup.php";
        ?>
        <label for="nbImg">Selectionner le nombre d'image que vous voulez inserrer : </label>
        <select name="nbImg">
            <?php  $nb = 10;
                  for ($i= 0; $i<=$nb; $i++){
                    ?>
                        <option name="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                    <?php
                  }             
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="img_upload_content">
        <div id="content_head">
            <div class="title_name">Selection fichier</div>
            <div class="title_desc">Description</div>
            <div class="title_price">Prix</div>
            <div class="title_error">status</div>
        </div>      
        <div id="content_list">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="img_upload_foot">

        <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" id="send" />


    </div>
</form>
```

***js***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name=nbImg]").hide();
    $("#send").hide();
    $("select[name=gal]").change(function(){

        var galSelect = $(this).val();
        if (galSelect != "none"){
            $("select[name=nbImg]").fadeIn("fast");
            $("select[name=nbImg]").change(function(){

                var selfElem = $(this);

                var nbImg = selfElem.val();

                $("#content_list").empty();



                for (var i = 1; i <= nbImg ; i++){
                    $("#content_list").append("<p id=\"file#"+i+"\"><span class=\"name\"><input type=\"file\" name=\"img[]\"id=\"img\" /></span><span class=\"desc\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"desc\" name=\"desc\" /></span><span class=\"price\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"price\" name=\"price\" /></span><span class=\"error\"></span></p>");
                }

                $("#send").fadeIn("fast");

                $("#send").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var form    =   $(this).parents("form");
                    var p       =   form.find("p");


                    var action = "/module/galerie/traitement/traitimg.php";
                    var desc = form.find("input[name=desc]").val();
                    var gal = $("select[name=gal]").val();
                    var price = form.find("input[name=price]").val();

                    var formData = new FormData();

                    jQuery.each($(p).find('input[name^="img"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                        formData.append('img-'+i, file);
                        formData.append('desc', desc);
                        formData.append('price', price);
                        formData.append('gal', gal);
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url :action,
                            type : "POST",
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            data: formData,
                            success: function(formData){

                            }
                        });

                    });


                    return false;

                });



            });
        }else{$("select[name=nbImg]").fadeOut("fast");}
    });
```

i don't really know if it's possible to do so.

Anyway thanks for the help you can provide me

***EDIT***

So i tried this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= nbImg; i++){
                        jQuery.each($(p).find('input[name^="img"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                            var formData = new FormData();
                            formData.append('img-'+i, file);
                            formData.append('desc', desc);
                            formData.append('price', price);
                            formData.append('gal', gal);
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                beforeSend : function(){
                                    $(".error").empty().append("<img src=\"/media/design/img/loader.gif\"/>");
                                },
                                url :action,
                                type : "POST",
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                data: formData,
                                success: function(formData){
                                    $(".error").empty().append("<img src=\"/media/design/img/v.png\"/>");
                                }
                            });

                        });
                    }
```

It's sending all the file at the same time and when i remove the "for" loop it'll send just the first one

```
jQuery.each($(p).find('input[name^="img"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                            var formData = new FormData();
                            formData.append('img-'+i, file);
                            formData.append('desc', desc);
                            formData.append('price', price);
                            formData.append('gal', gal);
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                beforeSend : function(){
                                    $(".error").empty().append("<img src=\"/media/design/img/loader.gif\"/>");
                                },
                                url :action,
                                type : "POST",
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                data: formData,
                                success: function(formData){
                                    $(".error").empty().append("<img src=\"/media/design/img/v.png\"/>");
                                }
                            });

                        });
```

Comment: sorry didn't say hi :p

Comment: It looks like you are already on your way to the solution. Can you describe where it fails? :)

Comment: why dont u use 2 forms i.e. 1form for 1 I/P n 2form for another and give time delay using JS for form submit..

Comment: Your code should sent an ajax request per file, as it is now. But I would recommend you to write this piece of code "var formData = new FormData();" inside of your jQuery.each loop, as you are just adding more and more files to the form data in each iteration.

Comment: well i did a foreach loop but it's sending all the files and i don't know how to send file per file

Comment: Ashish sorry didn't understand what you said ca you explain it please ?

Comment: I am assuming there's some sort of file upload functionality here, if we are talking about files? What is actually rendered by the MODULE.DS? What is the type of input[name^="img"] tag that you are finding?

Comment: the input [name^="img"] is a file type. And module.ds..... is a path for a php script. Well i don't think the problem is coming from here because with a loop all the files are sent and saved.

Comment: Am really in a pinch up please ?